# A strict subset of $B\times C$, whose projections are $C,B$: how to explain in words that this is not a contradiction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider a set $A$ such that:

1. $A\subset B\times C$.
2. The projection of $A$ on $B$ is equal to $C$.
3. The projection of $A$ on $C$ is equal to $B$.

How can I explain "in words" that 1 does not contradict 2,3?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you don't like about  what you wrote. Are you trying to explain the idea to a nonmathematican?

Comment: If I had to do this I would probably give a small (2x2) example - does that count as an explanation "in words"?

Comment: Maybe consider the diagonal of a chessboard?

Comment: Also for intuition, $B\times C$ has many more elements than $B$ and $C$, so we "should" be able to remove many of them without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the projection of $A$ onto $B$ is $C$ then $C\subset B$ and if the projection of $A$ onto $C$ is $B$ then $B\subset C$ so $B=C$.

For $A$ to be a proper subset we need to omit some of the pairs. Take $B=C=\{\text{world cities}\}$ and let $A=\{(\text{New York}, c): c\in B\}\cup\{(c,\text{London}): c\in B\}$. Then $A$ is a proper subset because it doesn't contain $(\text{Moscow,} \text{Barcelona})$ but its projections are surjective.

In words, we would say this is not a contradiction because $B$ can equal $C$ and $A$ can contain pairs such that every element of $B$ is first for a pair of elements of $A$ and every element of $B$ is second for a pair of elements of $A$ but not every element of $B$ is paired up with every other element of $B$.